# setTimeout hover with TweenMax

Tags: jquery, settimeout, gsap

I'm trying to add a setTimeout on hover to avoid a bug if the mouse is moving fast on links.

[My code](https://codepen.io/leodurand/pen/eeYGrO)

I tried a simple setTimeout but nothing

```
setTimeout(function over(){
  TweenMax.to($(this).find(".title_thumb"), 0.3, {display:"block" , opacity:"1" , marginTop:"20px" , ease:Power2.easeOut , delay:"0.2"})
  TweenMax.to($(this).find(".view_thumb"), 0.3, {display:"block" , opacity:"1" , ease:Power2.easeOut , delay:"0.5"});
  TweenMax.to($(this).find(".layer_thumb"), 0.02, {opacity:"1" , ease:Power2.easeOut});
}, 200);
```

and also with this code but didn't find to make it work...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var delay=200, setTimeoutConst;
    $('.thumb').hover(function(){
        setTimeoutConst = setTimeout(function(){
            $(".thumb").hover(over, out);
            function over(){
                TweenMax.to($(this).find(".title_thumb"), 0.3, {display:"block" , opacity:"1" , marginTop:"20px" , ease:Power2.easeOut , delay:"0.2"})
                TweenMax.to($(this).find(".view_thumb"), 0.3, {display:"block" , opacity:"1" , ease:Power2.easeOut , delay:"0.5"});
                TweenMax.to($(this).find(".layer_thumb"), 0.02, {opacity:"1" , ease:Power2.easeOut});
            }
            function out(){
                TweenMax.to($(this).find(".title_thumb"), 0.3, {display:"none" , opacity:"0" , marginTop:"0px" , ease:Power2.easeOut})
                TweenMax.to($(this).find(".view_thumb"), 0.2, {display:"none" , opacity:"0" , marginTop:"0px" , ease:Power2.easeOut})
                TweenMax.to($(this).find(".layer_thumb"), 0.02, {opacity:"0" , ease:Power2.easeOut});
            }
        }, delay);
    },function(){
        clearTimeout(setTimeoutConst );
    })
})
```

If you have any idea I would be really glad !

Answer (score 0):

I made a pen for you

[HoverIntent CodePen](https://codepen.io/Zuriel/pen/JOoGvx)

Just add hoverintent into your scripts after jQuery, then replace any hover call in JS with hoverIntent

```
    $(".thumb").hoverIntent(over, out);
```

Comment: Is there a way to make it with jQuery only ? Also, I don't get what does it do ?

Comment: https://briancherne.github.io/jquery-hoverIntent/  Its a supplement to jQuery.  What does it do?  goto that demo example and move your mouse rapidly back and forth across the 4 squares.  When you stop moving the all keep animating because they are qued.  HoverIntent has a initial delay that you can customize that prevents the functions from running until the timeout finishes and then runs, you can move your mouse rapidly over the other examples and see the difference.

Comment: the first demo on that link is normal jQuery without hoverintent.  the rest of the links are with hoverIntent to show the benefit

Comment: I still have some elements ("View projects") showed after I moved my mouse rapidly back and forth.

Comment: right, that is a tweenmax issue at that point, i tried to clean some of it up but what you really want to do is create a TimeLine in tweenmax.  then when you rollover, timeline start.  when you rollout, timeline reverse.  This way you will never have any left over artifacts, your either in playing forward on the timeline till it stops, or you are rolloing out and its back to its stock positions (but very elegant)

Comment: This is what I did for now, but I really wanted to get a different hover out. I still find a way to make the reverse faster. I guess it's okay. ^^ Thanks for your help though !